# Make an array A with the result of each value of array B splitted by pipe

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings. Some of the strings within this array have a pipe character. I would like to split the strings by "|" and store all the unique values into a new array.

What would be an efficient way to get a temporary array with all the splited values in it, without using poor performance loops?

Once I have the temporary array with all the splited values in it, I plan de remove all duplicates like this :
var result = [...new Set(result)]

```
var arr = ["A|B|C","B|A","E|A|D","F"]

// result does not have to be sorted
var expectedResult = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
```

Comment: use String split() function.

Comment: You want performance, here is a quick [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/ujl4fgp61f/1) sans `Set()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get a single array, and use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to retain unique elements:

```js
const array = ["A|B|C","B|A","E|A|D","F"];
const result = [...new Set(array.flatMap(v => v.split('|')))];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Never would have thought about flatMap. Much better than my loops. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`.join('|')` array as a string with pipes between all letters, then `.split('|')` by the pipe and then remove dupes with `Set()`

```js
let data = ["A|B|C", "B|A", "E|A|D", "F"];

console.log([...new Set(data.join('|').split('|'))]);
```

Comment: Smart, I like this one!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```js
const result = arr.map(item => item.split("|")).flat();
const deduped = [...new Set(result)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```js
const inputArray = ["A|B|C","B|A","E|A|D","F"];
const result = inputArray.reduce((acc, value) => acc.push(...value.split('|')) && acc, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const splitSet = (arr) => {
    const set = new Set();

    for(const item of arr) {
        const splited = item.split("|");
        for(const piece of splited) {
            set.add(piece);
        }
    }   
    
    return Array.from(set);
}

splitSet(arr); //result
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is this

```
const arr = ["A|B|C","B|A","E|A|D","F"];
const flatArr = arr.join('|').split('|');

const expectedResult = [...new Set(flatArr)];
```